# What is the meaning yellow service "started" status on Homebrew?

Tags: homebrew

When I tried `brew services list` command, dnsmasq, nginx status started but yellow. php71 and mysql is started and green.

Previously when my Mysql status started but yellow Mysql doesnt work.

Now my nginx and dnsmasq status started and yellow but everthing works fine.

What is the meaning **started** but yellow written status? Everything ok or?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Unfortunately the yellow color means status `unknown`. Wonder why it says started though.

I just found out because the status for apache 2.2 on OS X 10.11.6 is yellow as well. Don't know if it's actually working properly.

Here's what the homebrew-services `ServicesCli` code says

> # For backwards-compatability showing unknown state as started in yellow colour

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-services/blob/6e7ea0cff515df8b5d53a6e3066e16cf5e94d03a/lib/services_cli.rb#L147:L159

EDITS: Update code reference. Thanks @SidOfc

Comment: Mine says started and yellow quite often. It's basically wrong, it means errored.

Comment: This will clarify things a little for you.  

[icebrkr@ingram ~]$ HOMEBREW_DEVELOPER=1 brew services list

Answer (score 31):

The following steps worked to solve this for me:

1. Remove the `postmaster.pid` file for your service (i.e. `rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid`).
2. Restart your service on homebrew (i.e. `brew services restart postgresql`).

Comment: Thanks for this comment, that does not really answer the initial question but worked like a charm for me!

Comment: This worked great, can anyone give some more detail on why this works and what's going on?

Comment: First upvote of a "this was the most amazing solution to a problem that does not actually answer the question" and yet....it kind of does answer the question I was looking for :)

Comment: For some context: https://postgresapp.com/documentation/troubleshooting.html#the-data-directory-contains-an-old-postmasterpid-file--the-data-directory-contains-an-unreadable-postmasterpid-file

Comment: this totally worked for me, amazing! thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I had this just now for mariadb, and solved it by running `brew reinstall mariadb`.

I had just installed a new version of MAMP and I suspect something of MAMP had overwritten something related to mariadb.

Answer (score 0):

If your configuration can make the service run as either daemon or non-daemon, do not make it daemon.

I found the yellow status when I configured `daemon` in haproxy.cfg. After I removed `daemon` in the configuration and restarted it (including killing the process, as brew does not really know which process to stop in the daemon mode of haproxy), HAProxy showed the bright green ‘started’ status. And I can now really stop it with `brew services stop`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

One cause for the yellow, indiciating an error, is that the Postgres version updated when you ran `brew upgrade`.

To see if this is the case, run `tail /usr/local/var/log/postgres.log` and check if you have an error like `The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 11, which is not compatible with this version 12.3`

In this case, our data files are v11, but postgres is now v12, so to use the old version:

```sh
mv /usr/local/var/postgres /usr/local/var/postgresql@11
brew services stop postgres
brew install postgresql@11
brew link --force postgresl@11
brew services start postgresql@11
```

Answer (score -4):

I think its yellow for the apps that are started by the root user. If you type `sudo brew services list` you get every app that's started by root as green, and the ones that are started by other users as yellow.

Comment: Don't think that's it... I have yellow and green status, both for my user

Comment: The yellow color, while it means unknown, is probably indicative that it may be owned by `root` (or by a different user that is in an inaccessible group from the current user). In fact, the owner of the process is listed right next to the status column.