# brew services not completely started - mongodb

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

I have this script:

```
set -e;

brew services stop mongodb | cat; # just in case it's running

sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/mongodb
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/var/mongodb
sudo ln -s "$1" /usr/local/var/mongodb

brew services start mongodb
```

where I symlink some data to the brew services data location.

After running the script, I get:

```
Stopping `mongodb`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `mongodb` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb)
Password:
db path => '/Users/alexamil/mongodump_dev'
==> Successfully started `mongodb` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb)
```

but then 5 minutes later, I cannot connect to mongo, and I see:

[image]

started is yellow not green, which means something is wrong.

Anyone know what this is about?

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41873704/what-is-the-meaning-yellow-service-started-status-on-homebrew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, I wasn't actually pointing mongod to the right directory, since my symlink code was incorrect.

But if `brew services ls` shows a yellow "started" line, then that means something went wrong and the service hasn't actually started yet. Dear brew authors - maybed use a different word other than "started", maybe "starting" would be a good start :)

Comment: Homebrew authors won’t see this; please open an issue on the repo if you can.