# Mac OS X: brew services list status yellow

Tags: macos, homebrew

Hi why my brew services are turning to yellow status. Even a simple logrotate utility is now turned to yellow state in brew. Not able to figure out from googling.

Not only me, lot of my friends also facing the same issue.
[image]

How should i debug and find what causing this errors.

Note:

Steps already taken

1. brew uninstall logrotate kibana logstash
2. brew install logrotate kibana logstash
3. Restarted my MAC Book
4. Upgraded my brew services

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41873704/what-is-the-meaning-yellow-service-started-status-on-homebrew ?

Comment: @9bO3av5fw5 that is not helpful. No solution worked for me.

Comment: @sathish is this still an issue for you? Sometimes it's a permissions issue. Try to `cd` into the directory of your dependency and see what your permissions are if you're not running as root or under a group that has ownership. For example, I see you have nginx `/Library/Logs/nginx` and use the `chown` or `chgrp` commands to configure to your liking. That solved my problem when spinning up services via brew and seeing a yellow status.

Comment: @CarlsBad505 yes this still issue. let me check your solution